# Adding list of error-bars to plot

Tags: plotting, code-request, code-review

I have a basic question about adding error-bars to a plot. It seems that the built-in errorbar function is no longer available, could someone advise on what would be an efficient way to include the error bars list data to the points of the following plot (which renders without problem)? Thanks for any assistance:

````
\[Mu] = {10, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 100000, 
   150000, 200000};

Data = {0.00179619, 0.00176211, 0.00180302, 0.00172858, 0.00172073, 
   0.00170652, 0.00170215, 0.00169661, 0.0016873, 0.00168856, 
   0.00168662};

B = N[1/(2 (300))]

Show[ListPlot[Thread[{\[Mu], Data}], 
  PlotRange -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {0.00165, 0.00185}}, 
  Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Purple, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic], 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Blue, 
   Line[{{Min[\[Mu]], 1/(2*300)}, {Max[\[Mu]], 1/(2*300)}}], 
   Text["B", {Min[\[Mu]], 1/(2*300)}, {0, -1.5}]}]

errorbars = Sqrt[Data/\[Mu]]

```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Data = {0.00179619, 0.00176211, 0.00180302, 0.00172858, 0.00172073, 
   0.00170652, 0.00170215, 0.00169661, 0.0016873, 0.00168856, 
   0.00168662};

μ = {10, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 100000, 
   150000, 200000};

errorbars = Sqrt[Data/μ];

data2 = Transpose[{μ, Around @@@ Transpose[{Data, errorbars}]}];

B = N[1/(2  (300))];

ListLogLinearPlot[data2,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-0.012, 0.016}},
 Frame -> True,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Purple,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Blue, 
   InfiniteLine[{{1, 1/(2*300)}, {2, 1/(2*300)}}], 
   Text["B", {2, 1/(2*300)}, {0, -1.5}]}]
```

[image]